# My build size randomly doubled Unity3d Andriod

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I build my game at first time the file size : 23mb 10 min later a build again and i got : 50mb

here the build report:
Build Report

Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):

Textures               4.8 mb    23.7%

Meshes                 0.0 kb    0.0%

Animations             2.5 kb    0.0%

Sounds                 0.0 kb    0.0%

Shaders                437.1 kb  2.1%

Other Assets           488.5 kb  2.3%

Levels                 4.7 kb    0.0%

Scripts                1.1 mb    5.6%

Included DLLs          13.3 mb   65.0%

Total User Assets      20.5 mb   100.0%

Complete build size    225.9 mb

Used Assets and files from the Resources folder, sorted by uncompressed size:

biggest is unity build in extra with 6mb. Second is textmeshpro with 1mb. The rest is smaller than 1 mb

I dont want to copy and paste the all but you see this not should be 50mb. Complete build size 225.9 mb mb is ridiculously big. Why this happening? i check many video & article in topic but still dont know

Comment: exported in Il2cpp, netstandard 2.0, target architectures : armv7, arm64

Comment: Does it do the same if you wipe the build fonder and build? what did you do between builds?

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you. I think i found a problem. I deleted the firebase analytics package and my build size decresed 120mb. So i reimported the package and now the file size 34mb. the build size: 163mb